# Jasper Report : add header to group

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReport.
I have created a report with a group in it.
I realize I have forgotten to add a group header.
Is it possible to add it without being forced to delete the group and recreate it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it without recreate group.

ex) If you want to add the below "RF" group header.

[image]

1.Right click on "RF Group Header".
2.select "Add Band" from context menu.

Just it.

Also, you can delete group-header without delete group.
Right click and select "Delete Band".